# Activities, Events and List Views

Tags: event, list-view, activities

The question is more about the understanding of Salesforce features rather than looking for any specific solution.

Recently, I've been closely working on the objects Activities and Events and it seems that:

- creating Actions and Buttons on Events is possible but it is not possible to add them to the List View Button Layout as there is no existing one,
- creating Buttons is possible on Activities which then can be added to the List View Button Layout. However, Activities can't be added as a tab on any app, therefore the List View can't be used. It even can't be used in a Lightning web component e.g. on a home page.

Is this all correct or am I missing here something? Why would Salesforce give these options whithout allowing them to be used in practice?

Answer (score 0):

Activities are related to a parent relationship and would be available as related lists on their Parent records such as Accounts, Contacts, etc. If you want to use the options to include some actions, you have to use Global Actions options available and you can design your own Publisher Layouts for certain actions like New Task, New Events, Log a Call, etc.

Comment: It makes sense with the Activities and related lists on parent objects.
Global Actions wouldn't let me e.g. mass update a field on mutliple Events. However, I can create an Update Record action on the Event object but how can I then use it? I definitely can't add it to the Activity list view layout.

Comment: when you want to do mass update a field, why do you need a UI ? You can do that behind the scene

Comment: The mass update of an event status should be available to the users who can't do it behind the scenes. Since it is possible to create the Action mass update a field on Events, I thought it would be also possible to add it to the UI.